# High volume category list causes slow load

Tags: categories, control-panel

My customer has 3500 categories in a 3 level hierarchy. This is causing some significant pain when adding categories to an entry. The server delivers the categories via ajax in 9sec, but the browser then takes 3-5 minutes to push the html segment into the modal dialog.

Is there any way to handle this a little more efficiently? I need to be able to select from any of the 3500 categories, but would love to limit the initial display to only the top one or two levels of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with category and structured section UI in the control panel.

Performance actually starts degrading around the 3-400 item mark, but it will be addressed in the upcoming 2.2 release.